# AngularJS search filter with nested arrays?

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angular-filters

AngularJS search filter with nested arrays which contains similar "keys" for all.

Please take a look at [pen](http://codepen.io/vilaskumkar/pen/akXRoQ) it will explain in details.

I have pasted dataset below where I have searchable text as "value". I'm able to search "Product Item". Now I want to search data by each field. 
i.e.

- Product Item
- Width
- Height
- Color
- Weight
- Window

data format is as below :

```
$scope.dataset = {"items": [
                {"itemid": "12345","unitqty": 1,"itemdescription": "Cool Product","favorite":true,"attributegroups": [[{"type": "itemID","title": "Product Item","value": "12345","action": "viewitem"},{"type": "width","title": "Width","value": "1in","action": ""},{"type": "height","title": "Height","value": "2in","action": ""}],[{"type": "color","title": "Color","value": "Mauve","action": ""},{"type": "weight","title": "Weight","value": "20lb Bond","action": ""},{"type": "window","title": "Window","value": "none","action": ""}],[{"type": "detail","title": "Detail","value": "Value","action": ""},{"type": "detail","title": "Detail","value": "Value","action": ""},{"type": "detail","title": "Detail","value": "Value","action": ""}]]},
                {"itemid": "12355","unitqty": 1,"itemdescription": "Cool Product","attributegroups": [[{"type": "itemID","title": "Product Item","value": "12355","action": "viewitem"},{"type": "width","title": "Width","value": "1in","action": ""},{"type": "height","title": "Height","value": "2in","action": ""}],[{"type": "color","title": "Color","value": "Mauve","action": ""},{"type": "weight","title": "Weight","value": "20lb Bond","action": ""},{"type": "window","title": "Window","value": "none","action": ""}],[{"type": "detail","title": "Detail","value": "Value","action": ""},{"type": "detail","title": "Detail","value": "Value","action": ""},{"type": "detail","title": "Detail","value": "Value","action": ""}]]},            
                {"itemid": "12366","unitqty": 1,"itemdescription": "Cool Product","favorite":true,"attributegroups": [[{"type": "itemID","title": "Product Item","value": "12366","action": "viewitem"},{"type": "width","title": "Width","value": "1in","action": ""},{"type": "height","title": "Height","value": "2in","action": ""}],[{"type": "color","title": "Color","value": "Mauve","action": ""},{"type": "weight","title": "Weight","value": "20lb Bond","action": ""},{"type": "window","title": "Window","value": "none","action": ""}],[{"type": "detail","title": "Detail","value": "Value","action": ""},{"type": "detail","title": "Detail","value": "Value","action": ""},{"type": "detail","title": "Detail","value": "Value","action": ""}]]}
            ]};
});
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: @Aron Sorry for incomplete question, updated now.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your pen, your input field has a ng-model, `<input type="text" placeholder="Item Number" ng-model="attribute.value"/>` You need to place ng-model for other fields too like width, height etc.

Here is a sample:

```
<input ng-model="search.name">
<input ng-model="search.phone">
<input ng-model="search.secret">
<tr ng-repeat="student in class | filter:{name: search.name, phone: search.phone}">
```

Here is how you do with-in yours.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Width" ng-model="attribute.width"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Height" ng-model="attribute.height"/>

<div ng-repeat="item in dataset.items | filter : {attributegroups : {value : attribute.value, width: attribute:width, height: attribute.height}}" class="items">
```

Comment: Agreed!, but my pen dataset having all values as "value", please take closer look at $scope.dataset. and ng-model "attribute.value" is actually a filter '<div ng-repeat="item in dataset.items | filter : {attributegroups : {value : attribute.value}}">'

Comment: not working for me, can you please fork my pen and make yours with your code?

Comment: @VilasKumkar: the problem is attribute.value is same for all the types, so its very tricky to have multiple input field.... in your first input field... all the search items would work... attribute.value is for every input field... but that would create problem... http://codepen.io/vilaskumkar/pen/akXRoQ

Comment: What you can do is to create dynamic input fields, then attach the dynamic objects ng-model to your each input field... so ng-model would become like this... ng-model="attribute[0].value" where it would link with product item, then for your second input field it would be ng-model="attribute[1].value" which would link with width... something like this http://codepen.io/vilaskumkar/pen/akXRoQ